# Rewrite C code Using Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have to rewrite code that references a 2-dimensional array using pointers instead of array operators.
How would I rewrite this:

```
...
else 
    array[i][j] = 'x';
...
```

So, I'm going to be setting the array to 'x' at that index. How would I do this with a pointer?

Comment: Is `array` a real 2D array or a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of characters?

Comment: @CarlNorum , it's a real 2D array of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `array` is `char array[x][y]` then

```
 *(*(array + i) + j) = 'x';
```

I mean, it's ugly and I probably wouldn't do that, but it will work.

```
*(array + i)
```

returns another `char[]` at index `i`.  So, you then offset again into that using `j`.  You can (should) break that up into a few lines so that it is easy to scan.

Answer (score 1):

The operation `a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)` (that is, you're dereferencing a pointer plus an offset).

You should be able to generalize that to higher-dimensioned arrays (hint: you'll be replacing `a` with a similar expression).

There are less useful homework exercises, but not that many.

Answer (score 0):

If `array` is `char[n][m]`, and you have `char *p=array`, the solution is `p[m*i+j]='x';`, but you should consider using pointer to array:

```
char (*p2d)[m]=array;
p2d[i][j]='x';
```